# Confidential data encryption on ethereum

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, matrix-multiplication, trusted-platform-module

I already built a supply chain that is able to collect product information on Ethereum. Now, that data can be confidential, but I still want to do Matrix calculations on it. I came across homomorphic encryption, but I'm not sure if it would help me. My product information has a JSON format like that:

```
{  
"Timestamp": UNIX,  
"Materials": [  
{  
 "Chemical1": XXXX mol,  
 "Chemical2": XXXX mol,  
}  
],      
"CO2": XXX kg,  
"Energy": XXX kWh,  
"Water": XXX m²,  
"Price": XXX €,  
"Amount": XXX,  
"Totalprice": Price * Amount   
}
```

I want to be able to extract the specific information I want from that file and calculate with it but it also has to be confidential/encrypted. Does someone have an idea which method would be the best to do that and is there maybe a JavaScript package for that?

Comment: What needs to be confidential?  The CO2 level, or the fact that the CO2 level is noted?  Or, just the price?  Also, what needs to be computed?  What are the security requirements?  If you extract some information, will you be able to understand it?  Who is allowed to do the decryption?

Comment: So, in the end this should be data about products a company produces and that will build the life cycle inventory to calculate the life cycle assessment, because if you have the data exposed to everyone you could lead back what kind of machinery or processes the company uses. The data should be encrypted by the company and only be seen by the company that provides the data. Then the LCA should be calculated and the result can be seen by an independent institution like a tax office and some company that checks the ecological footprint of the product. At least that's what I have in my mind atm.

Comment: @poncho what do you think?